# Python Flask with STUN

Tags: python, flask, stun

I'm developing a simple Flask based server that can communicate with peer applications (other similar servers) on internet. The application can be behind a NAT. So I'm trying to resolve the external IP and port through a stun server by using pystun.

```
import stun
nat_type,external_ip,external_port=stun.get_ip_info()
```

The port returned is 54320. Problem is when I try http://external_ip:54320 the request is not reaching the Flask app. http://external_ip:5000 is also not working, 5000 being the internal port used (I know this should not work, but tried it anyways). There are no firewalls. I have run Flask with host="0.0.0.0". 
to add.. i dont want to do explicit port mapping in the router.. is there a way flask can listen to a port that is accessible from external addresses and figure out external port through stun?

Comment: Is the port being mapped correctly?

Comment: i dont think so.. but how to check that? i dont think its getting mapped correctly because everytime i query with pystun it always returns the same port 54320

Comment: to add.. i dont want to do explicit port mapping in the router.. is there a way flask can listen to a port that is accessible from external addresses and figure out external port through stun

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to host a server behind a NAT without doing an explicit port mapping.  The NAT is also acting as a firewall. The node behind the NAT can make outbound TCP connections, but the NAT will block any inbound connections.

STUN doesn't help here because it only helps nodes behind NATs discover their own port mappings.  To allow connection to be established after STUN, you typically have to do a hole punching step, which involves both endpoints simultaneously trying to connect to each other.

The one idea you could try is to use [UPNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), which is a protocol that many NATs support for dynamically creating port mappings.  There's some opens source libraries that might work.

But the easier solution is to just configure your NAT to have an explicitly port mapping. (e.g. port 50000 maps to your PC's internal IP address at a specific port).